# Why are reflexive spaces called like that?

Tags: terminology, normed-spaces, reflexive-space

A normed spaces $(X, \| \cdot \|)$ is called **reflexive** if the evaluation map $X \to X^{**}$ is an isomorphism.
If $X$ is reflexive, it's not analytically distinguishable from it's bidual space $X^{**}$ because they are isometrically isomorphic.

But why does the term "reflexive" make sense? I know that for a relation to be reflexive, every element has to be related to itself, does this notion cary over to normed spaces?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: For a **finite** dimensional space, X** and X are isomorphic.  For infinite spaces, that is not in general true but "reflexive" spaces are, as you say, "isometrically isomorphic".  That is then like saying "X= X".

Comment: It's just a word.  It doesn't have anything to do with reflexive relations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, for a binary relation $R$ on a Cartesian product $X \times X$ of a set with itself to be *reflexive* means that, for each $x \in X$, the relation $xRx$ holds: $x$ is $R$-related to itself.

So, read "reflexive" as, kind of, "self".

For a normed space $X$, the relation is not on $X \times X$, but on $X \times X^{*}$.  A similar relation is on $X^* \times X^{**}$.  A composition of these two relations is a relation on $X \times X^{**}$, which is the evaluation map.  For this relation to be reflexive, we must have $X$ and $X^{**}$ be algebraically and topologically indistinguishable.

Comment: How is the evaluation map a relation?

Comment: A function is a special case of a relation.